# How to Logging To SQL Server With NLog in .Net Core 3.1?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, logging, nlog

In .net Core 2.2 according to [Nlog documentations](https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/Database-target) i can write logs in sql server but after update .net Core to 3.1, that doesn't work.

My goal is recording logs in sql server and this doesn't matter what nuget package(nlog, serilog, elmah, log4net, ...) be used.

Comment: Try give an example of your `NLog.config` that you are using, and the nuget-package that you are using for SqlClient (Hint `Microsoft.Data.SqlClient` is the new one).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

refer to [this article](https://github.com/damienbod/AspNetCoreNlog). but you sure that you must add each 3 following packages:

`NLog.Web.AspNetCore`,
`System.Data.SqlClient`,
`Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools`

Comment: thanks man. i resolved my problem with that article you shared.

Comment: You're right but your reply was defective because that need more steps that you missed those.Of course you help me and i modified your reply and mark that as answer. that's OK? :)

Answer (score 0):

as mr.Brando Zhang answered,i do steps according by article that mr.Brando Zhang shared.

my problem was that i didn't add the `System.Data.SqlClient` package
and then i did the rest of the steps as mentioned in  [this article](https://github.com/damienbod/AspNetCoreNlog).

Comment: You're right but your reply was defective because that need more steps that you missed those.Of course you help me and  i modified your reply and mark that as answer. 
that's OK? :)